# How to show a little part of the second item of my owl-carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I work on the developpment of a mobile first website.
So, on mobile device I only show one item of my owl-carousel but I want to show just a little part of the second item to instil at the user that's a slider but I can't.
I allready do this :
[image: Carousel operational]
And that's the code :

```
//JS
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:1,
    nav:false,
    dots:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
  });
});

//CSS
#scrollerParent {
    width: 718px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 295px;
    left: 36px;
}

#articles-scroll {
    width: 718px;
}

.article {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 342px;
    height: 629.27px;
}

.article img {
    width: 342px;
}

.titreArticle {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230.07px;
    left: 23.3px;
    color: #20335D;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.corpsArticle {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 366.07px;
    left: 23.3px;
    color: #888888;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.article span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 563.47px;
    left: 23.3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888888;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

This first version is operationnal, it work, I can slide, but I want to show a little part of the second item like this version :
[image: Carousel no operational]
To get it I just change :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:1,
    nav:false,
    dots:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2 //I just change this
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
  });
});
```

But that's not operational. When I try to slide, I'm stuck on the first item. That's slide but it going back on the first item instead of staying on the second.
I think the JS/jQuery of my first version is good but maybe the CSS is'nt.
I also know we can modify the CSS with some jQuery code but I have no idea how.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [stagPadding](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html):

You can change your code to this:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  stagePadding: 50, // Or any number you would like
  loop: false,
  margin: 1,
  nav: false,
  dots: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 2 //I just change this
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know but I don't think that's what I search. The stagePadding just shift first item on the right if I do with 1 item and if I set 2 items, the entire slider is push on the right also and didn't fix my slide problem : when I slide, the slider wont stop on the second item and go back on the first one.

Comment: Have you checked the link I posted? I tried it on mobile phone and desktop. It works fine with no issues in displaying or sliding.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I check it but I can't make it work well.

Comment: It shift the first item on the left and I can't swipe and reach the second item.
(I work for a mobile display so I change the responsive: 0 to 1 item)

Comment: And I cant display a part of the second item :/

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question. but just in case anyone needs this..

what i do is to set negative margins on responsive `0` to purposely make the next item overlap the currently displayed item. then, make the content smaller in width by wrapping it with another div of smaller width.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: false,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1,
      margin: -100 //change this value based on your need (it need to be negative to show a part of the next item)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  padding-block: 1rem;
}

.owl-carousel .item div h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: xxx-large;
}

.owl-carousel .item div {
  height: 10em;
  width: 15em;
  background: #1b75d0;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 24em;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <div> <!-- on `.item`, you'll need to wrap your content with a div. later, set width to prevent overlap with the part of the next item -->
        <h1>1</h1> <!-- your content -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <h1>2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <h1>3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
        <h1>4</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

there is a way to display a part of the previous item when on the last item, but its a little complicated because it requires changing CSS based on a condition.

```
//jq
...
responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1,
      margin: -100,
      onChanged: adjustCarouselMargins //you can add a function here that trigger on changed of item display
    }
  }
...

function adjustCarouselMargins(event) {
    var itemCount = event.item.count;
    var currentItemIndex = event.item.index;
    var $lastItem = $(event.target).find('.owl-item:last-child');
    var $secondLastItem = $lastItem.prev();

    if (currentItemIndex === itemCount - 1) {
        $lastItem.css('margin-left', '15px'); //space between item, change based on your need
        $secondLastItem.css('margin-right', '0px'); //must be zero
        $secondLastItem.css('margin-left', '400px'); //you can change this size based on your need, basically moved the previous item to the right to show a part of its content when displaying the last item
    } else {
        $lastItem.css('margin-right', '-100px'); //this size must be equal to applied value of margin on owl-carousel 
        $lastItem.css('margin-left', '0px'); //must be zero to reset
        $secondLastItem.css('margin-right', '-100px'); //this size must be equal to applied value of margin on owl-carousel 
        $secondLastItem.css('margin-left', '0px'); //must be zero to reset
    }
}

//css
.owl-item {
    transition: margin-left ease .1s, margin-right ease .1s;
}
```

the code above is intended to provide insight into how to do it. however, it may vary based on your specific needs